# Converting T-SQL Procedure to PySpark Function

Tags: t-sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

So there is a code in T-SQL , majorly a procedure that I want to convert to Pyspark . Here is the T-SQL procedure -

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SEGMENTATION] (
    @COL_NM varchar(max),
    @INPUT_TABLE varchar(max),
    @COL_NM2 varchar(max),
    @ROW1 varchar(max),
    @ROW2 varchar(max),
    @ROW3 varchar(max),
    @ROW4 varchar(max),
    @ROW5 varchar(max),
    @ROW6 varchar(max),
    @OUTLIER varchar(max)
)
AS

DECLARE @SQ as VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQ1 as VARCHAR(MAX)

BEGIN

    SET @SQ = '
    DROP TABLE ##TMP
    SELECT *,
    SUM(' + @COL_NM + ') OVER(ORDER BY ' + @ROW1 + ' DESC, ' + @ROW2 + ' DESC, ' + @ROW3 + ' DESC, ' + @ROW4 + ' DESC, ' + @ROW5 + ' DESC, ' + @ROW6 + ' DESC) as CUM_SUM
    INTO ##TMP
    FROM ' + @INPUT_TABLE + '

    IF ' + @OUTLIER + ' = 1000000
    GOTO SKIP_OUTLIER_TREATMENT;

    UPDATE ##TMP
    SET CUM_SUM  = CUM_SUM - (SELECT SUM(' + @COL_NM + ') FROM ' + @INPUT_TABLE + ' WHERE ' + @COL_NM + ' >= ' + @OUTLIER + ')

    SKIP_OUTLIER_TREATMENT:

    DECLARE @MAX as DECIMAL(18,4)
    SELECT @MAX = max(CUM_SUM) from ##TMP
    UPDATE ##TMP
    SET ' + @COL_NM2 + ' = CASE WHEN ' + @COL_NM + ' > 0 THEN (11-CEILING(10*CUM_SUM/@MAX)) ELSE 0 END

    UPDATE ' + @INPUT_TABLE + '
    SET ' + @COL_NM2 + ' = B.' + @COL_NM2 + '
    FROM ' + @INPUT_TABLE + ' as A
    INNER JOIN
    ##TMP as B
    ON ISNULL(A.PCYC_ID,0) = ISNULL(B.PCYC_ID,0) and ISNULL(A.NPI,0) = ISNULL(B.NPI,0)

    UPDATE ' + @INPUT_TABLE + '
    SET ' + @COL_NM2 + ' = 10 WHERE ' + @COL_NM2 + ' = 11

    '

    PRINT(@SQ)
    EXEC(@SQ)

END;
```

So I tried converting this T-SQL procedure to PySpark but Spark was taking too long to run the function on data and also giving errors.

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you plan to replicate the massive security vulnerabilities the above has in PySpark too? I would *hope* not, that code is wide open to injection attacks...  I think I could do just about anything with the **20GB** of text injection you offer there... Why are you *not* using the correct data type for your dynamic objects (`sysname`) and properly quoting them (with `QUOTENAME`)?

Comment: Not the mention that it's generally advised to not use syntax such as `EXEC (@SQL);`. Such statements cannot be parametrised, which promote bad habits that result in security flaws like SQL injection; which the above is ***WIDE OPEN*** to. If you need to run a statement that is within a variable or literal string then use [`sys.sp_executesql`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql). Then you can easily parametrise the statement if you need to.

Comment: No not using Azure databricks , I am doing it  on jupyter notebook, hence need to create a pyspark function with same functionality

Comment: You have not posted your PySpark code. If you are asking us to help you debug, fix, and/or optimize your code, you need to show us what you have so far.

Comment: try to come up with pyspark version, it will be easier for you since you already know the logic, then we should be able to debug or refine it for you